# Properly catching a async function node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

My attempt was:

my server.js has the following:

```
const app = express();
app.get('/*', loader(filePath, observer));
```

The file i'm trying to call sometimes loads with errors, which bubbles up to be uncaughtExceptions which restarts the server. I need to catch it in the catch{} somehow

```
export default (htmlFilePath, observer) => async (req, res) => {
    try {
      .......
      .......
      .......

        const markupStream = renderToNodeStream(
          <Provider store={store}>
            <ConnectedRouter history={history} location={context}>
              <App/>
            </ConnectedRouter>
          </Provider>
        );

        if (context.url) {
          return res.redirect(301, context.url)
        }

        return fs.createReadStream(htmlFilePath)
          .pipe(htmlReplace('#root', markupStream))
          .pipe(replaceStream('__SERVER_DATA__', serialize(store.getState())))
          .pipe(res);
      } catch (err) {
        const errMarkup = renderToNodeStream(
          <Provider store={store}>
            <ConnectedRouter history={history} location={context}>
              <Error500 error={err}/>
            </ConnectedRouter>
          </Provider>
        );

        logger.log({
          level: 'error',
          message: `Rendering ${req.originalUrl} fallback to Error render method`,
          ...{
            errorMessage: err.message,
            stack: err.stack
          }
        });

        return fs.createReadStream(htmlFilePath)
          .pipe(htmlReplace('#root', errMarkup))
          .pipe(res.status(500));
      } finally {
        logger.info(`Request finished ${req.originalUrl} :: ${res.statusCode}`)
        end({ route: path, componentName: componentNames[0], code: res.statusCode })
        logger.profile(profileMsg);
      }
}
```

What's the right way to do this? My issue before doing `().catch(err` was that I always got `uncaughtException`, it did not ever go into the catch in the `try{}` `catch{}` within the function

Comment: `ssrStream` does not returns a promise, it returns a function, that returns a promise, that's why `ssStream().catch` is not a function.

Comment: I was trying to follow: https://www.valentinog.com/blog/throw-errors-async-functions-javascript/

Comment: That example, and your code are complete different things, it would be easier for us to help you, if we know what `ssrStream` is, and where are you going to use it. Because sometimes it's ok to let the error bubble up.

Comment: It's server-rendering for react. If I let it bubble up the node-server restarts which i'm trying to prevent. It's called from the express server by app.get('/*', loader(filePath, observer));

Comment: Well if it's use as an express middleware, I'll answer it, you should add that to your question.

Comment: I'm sorry. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When using an `async` express middleware, in order to catch any rejections and pass that rejection to the express error handler, you need a wrapper:

**async-handler.js**

```
const asyncHandler = fn => (req, res, next) => {
    return Promise
        .resolve(fn(req, res, next))
        .catch(next);
};

module.exports = asyncHandler;
```

**ssr-stream.js**

```
const ssrStream = (htmlFilePath, observer) => async (req, res) => {
    // If you wrap this middleware with asyncHandler
    // No need try/catch, you can let it bubble up, and it will go to express error middleware
    // Of course you can do it, and handle the custom error here, and let it bubble up for generic errors.
}

export default ssrStream;
```

**index.js**

```
const app = express();
const asyncHandler = require('./async-handler');
const loader = require('./ssr-stream');

// Wrap your async function, with asyncHandler
app.get('/foo', asyncHandler(async(req, res) => {
    throw new Error('Foo'); // This will go to the express error middleware
}));

app.get('/*', asyncHandler(loader(filePath, observer)));

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {

    // Handle the error type, and set the correct status code
    const status = 500;
    res
        .status(status)
        .end(err.message);
});
```

Comment: That `asyncHandler` is an awesome snippet, I'll have to remember that one.

Comment: Indeed it is! I don't start any of my projects without it :P, there probably are multiple packages in NPM with a snippet alike :)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I updated my first post, I realized I was way too short.

Comment: Show your exact error, because if you wrap your middlware as I described in my answer, all errors thrown inside the middleware will go to the express error handler.

Comment: If I wrap it like you describe, will it not ignore my catch in the ssr-stream? I want it to render        const errMarkup = renderToNodeStream(
          <Provider store={store}>
         .....)

Comment: the error i'm getting sometimes is when const markupStream = renderToNodeStream() get errors

Comment: If you have a `try/catch` inside your middleware, it won't be ignored, the `asyncHandler` will only catch unhandled errors inside your middleware.

Comment: still getting 2018-07-18T08:34:18.965Z [error] uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'from' of undefined. 2018-07-18T08:34:18.970Z [error]  Uncaught exception after adding your asyncHandler

Comment: .get('/*', asyncHandler(loader(filePath, observer)))
  .use((err, req, res, next) => {
    // Attempt to handle the error type, and set the correct status code
    const status = 500;
    res
        .status(status)
        .end(err.message);
  });

Comment: I don't see any from in your code, so post your full code or its impossible to help. You. If the error happens in a different asynchronous function, in a different tick of the event loop, that is not handled correctly, the error will bubble up, and nothing will catch it. My answer works for the posted code. If you keep changing the question, it's difficult to have an answer.

Answer (score -1):

You should check it in your function expression, not in the function declaration. In the function itself, just throw whenever there is an error. Then, wrap it in a try/catch block :

```
try {
  await ssrStream(htmlFilePath, observer);
} catch(e) {
  // Handle error here
}
```

It's also possible to chain a `catch` directly after your async function (which is essentially a promise) :

```
await ssrStream(htmlFilePath, observer)
  .catch(e => // handle error here);
```

Comment: Read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382989/properly-catching-a-async-function-node-js#comment89737870_51382989). `ssrStream` returns an `async` function, it isn't one.